# tomcat jdbc realm - j_security not redirecting

Tags: java, tomcat

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
       driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
       connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db"
       connectionName="user"
       connectionPassword="password"
       allRolesMode="authOnly"
       digest="SHA" 
       userTable="app" 
       userNameCol="login" 
       userCredCol="login"
       userRoleTable="login" 
       roleNameCol="group"/>  

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<form action="j_security_check" method="POST">
<tr>username:<td><input type="text"     name="j_username" style="width:100px;"></td></tr>
<tr> password:<td><input type="text"     name="j_ password " style="width:100px;"></td></tr>
<tr>< input type="submit"   name="btnLogin" value="login"></td></tr>
</form>
```

when deployed,I get HTTP Status 400 - Invalid direct reference to form login page

Here is browser console output..

```
Remote Address:::1:8080
Request URL:http://devserver:8080/testapp/j_security_check
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ta;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:53
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:JSESSIONID=BE7C932856A7794D9C780531A29FB25F
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://devserver:8080
Referer:http://devserver:8080/testapp/timeout.jsp
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
j_username:testuser
j_password:testuser
btnLogin:login
Response Headersview source
Connection:close
Content-Length:1054
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 27 Jun 2014 12:13:00 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

ALso I enabled log for realm and j_security_check is not redirecting after successfull login

```
Jun 27, 2014 5:42:49 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
FINE:  Not subject to any constraint
Jun 27, 2014 5:43:00 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
FINE: Security checking request POST /testapp/j_security_check
Jun 27, 2014 5:43:00 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator authenticate
FINE: Authenticating username 'testuser'
Jun 27, 2014 5:43:00 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator authenticate
FINE: Authentication of 'testuser' was successful
Jun 27, 2014 5:43:00 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator authenticate
FINE: Redirecting to original 'null'
Jun 27, 2014 5:43:00 PM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
FINE:  Failed authenticate() test ??/ testapp/j_security_check
```

Comment: you are showing the POST request when submitting the login form. Which URL did you use to start your app?

Comment: @CédricC App gets started with [link] http://localhost:8080/testapp/login.jsp

Answer (score 2):

Authentication in tomcat works by challenge. If you try to access a protected resources, Tomcat will redirect you to the login page. Once authenticated, it will redirect to the initial page requested.
If you access directly the login page there is no initial request hence the error:
`HTTP Status 400 - Invalid direct reference to form login page`

In your case, either try to acces a protected resource first or add `landingPage` attribute to your authenticator to get what you want ([see the documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Form_Authenticator_Valve))

EDIT: The landingPage attribute is only available since Tomcat7.

For exemple, in your context.xml file :

```
<Context>
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator" landingPage="connected.jsp"/>
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
   driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db"
   connectionName="user"
   connectionPassword="password"
   allRolesMode="authOnly"
   digest="SHA" 
   userTable="app" 
   userNameCol="login" 
   userCredCol="login"
   userRoleTable="login" 
   roleNameCol="group"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>dbrealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>  <role-name>ROLE1</role-name> </security-role>
    <security-role>  <role-name> ROLE2</role-name> </security-role>
    <security-role>  <role-name> ROLE3</role-name> </security-role>
In this case roles are not set in userprincipal

Comment: In galssfish... we have security-role-mapping , can u please guide how to configure mapping of user roles to groups.....

Comment: I don't know glassfish. But isn't the documentation sufficient ?http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html#bnbxv

Comment: I tried this in tomcat 6 and it didn't work. Is there any workaround

Comment: @user3733071 not really, there is no landingPage attribute for tomcat6, the best way is to put your home page behind the security-constraint and let tomcat do the work of displaying the login page.